# Simple shell script to send socket message

Tags: shell-script, socket, tcp-ip

For testing purposes I need to create a shell script that connects with a remote IP>Port and sends a simple text TCPIP Socket message.

Answer (score 51):

Using `nc` (`netcat`).

Server:

```
$ nc -l localhost 3000
```

Client:

```
$ nc localhost 3000
```

Both server and client will read and write to standard output/input.

This will work when the server and client are on the same machine.  Otherwise, change `localhost` to the external name of the server. On the server, you may also use `0.0.0.0` (or remove it altogether) to let the server bind to all available interfaces.

Slightly more interesting, a "server" that gives you the time of day if you connect to it and send it a `d`, and which quits if you send `q`:

Server (in `bash`):

```
#!/bin/bash

coproc nc -l localhost 3000

while read -r cmd; do
  case $cmd in
    d) date ;;
    q) break ;;
    *) echo 'What?'
  esac
done <&"${COPROC[0]}" >&"${COPROC[1]}"

kill "$COPROC_PID"
```

Client session:

```
$ nc localhost 3000
d
Thu Jan 12 18:04:21 CET 2017
Hello?
What?
q
```

(the server exits after `q`, but the client doesn't detect that it's gone until you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>).

Comment: If the server returns a result when client finishes sending data, the `ctrl+c` won't show the result. If using echo, e.g. `echo "cookie" | nc localhost 9090`, the client's output stream will be closed (eof sent) but the client will still wait for the server's result.

Comment: This has got to be one of the most concise and effective client-server examples out there. Thanks!

Comment: Replacing localhost for an external host name does not work straight forward, even with the external host being visible to the machine.

Comment: To make the communication between machines: remove localhost from the server code and run it on a machine that can be resolved from the one were the client code runs. 
In the client code change the localhost for the name of the host where the server code is running.

Comment: @PabloAdames This has been made more explicit in the answer now, I hope.

Comment: @Kusalananda, thanks for improving an already very useful answer!

Comment: `This will work when the server and client are on the same machine.` - no  it doesn't, the client version immediately fails with error code `1` and neither server not client print anything

Answer (score 24):

In general advice with `netcat` is better way.

But in `bash` and `ksh` you can also do this:

```
exec 3<>/dev/tcp/hostname/port
echo "request" 1>&3
response="$(cat <&3)"
```

Comment: what is `1>&3` ? I am not sure what that represents

Comment: in other words, why not just `echo "request" >&3`, I guess the 1 is just redundant

Comment: This might be better with an example.

Answer (score 6):

try netcat (e.g. nc )

```
echo GET / HTTP/1.0 | nc 0 80
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Thu, 12 Jan 2017 13:44:23 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Content-Length: 311
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

- in sample above I send a GET (`echo GET / HTTP/1.0` ) to my local http server
- If you don't want complex protocol, this might do the job.

Answer (score 3):

In many cases I have not had access to netcat/socat. I have also had issues with using bash's `exec` in a distributed computing environment.

Due to its prevalence, an alternative solution is to use GNU AWK's TCP/IP capabilities. It provides a simple syntax based around it's "two-way pipe" operator.

Here is a modified example from [this source](https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3132) that will send a TCP message over a socket:

```
BEGIN {
 NetService = "/inet/tcp/0/cs.wisc.edu/finger"
 print "coke" |& NetService
 close(NetService)
}
```

The full syntax for the address is: `/net-type/protocol/local-port/remote-host/remote-port`. When `local-port` is set to 0 the local host chooses the port automatically which is typically what you want. You can read more about `gawk`'s [TCP/IP networking capabilities](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/TCP_002fIP-Networking.html) in the supplied link.

It's worth noting that this can be shortened if you're only going to be sending one message per awk execution:

```
BEGIN {print "coke" |& "/inet/tcp/0/cs.wisc.edu/finger"}
```